# How to pass props to child components when using protected routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently developing a 'Train Ticket Reservation System' using ReactJS. Since users should login to access the services, I have used protected routes to render some components. Instead of using the default . So far I know how to send props with  using the render method. I want to know how to send props when using protected routes. Since the render method doesn't work with that.

This is my implementation of the protected route.

```
import React from 'react';  
import auth from './auth';  
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';  

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {  

    return(  
        <Route {...rest} render={props => {  

            if(auth.isAuthenticated()){  
                console.log(auth.isAuthenticated())  
                return <Component {...props}/>  
            }  
            else{  
                return <Redirect to={  
                    {  
                        pathname: '/',  
                        state:{  
                            from: props.location  
                        }  
                    }  
                } />  
            }  
            }} />  
    );  

};  

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

This is how I used protected route for navigation

```js
<ProtectedRoute  exact path="/Home/AboutUs" component={AboutUs}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass props to the `ProtectedRoute` component.

i.e.

```
<ProtectedRoute exact page="Home" path="/Home/AboutUs" component={AboutUs}/>
```

**To get the page props in the Component**

Since you have used destructuring.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => { ..... }
```

Except `component` props the remaining props are assigned to the variable `rest` after the spread operator.

So you can get the props from the variable `rest` which is an object.

```
<Component {...props} pageProps={rest.page} />  // pageProps="Home"
```